# On the problem of time?

Tags: time

> "In theoretical physics, the problem of time is a conceptual conflict
> between general relativity and quantum mechanics in that quantum
> mechanics regards the flow of time as universal and absolute, whereas
> general relativity regards the flow of time as malleable and
> relative. This problem raises the question of what time really
> is in a physical sense and whether it is truly a real, distinct
> phenomenon. It also involves the related question of why time seems to
> flow in a single direction, despite the fact that no known physical
> laws at the microscopic level seem to require a single direction.
> For macroscopic systems the directionality of time is directly linked
> to first principles such as the second law of thermodynamics."
>
> -[The Problem of Time page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_time) on Wikipedia

Has the problem of reconciling the subjective psychological experience of time, with the thermodynamic Arrow of Time, versus time in relation to photon light-clocks & quantum phenomena like caesium hyerfine transitions used in the SI definition of time, been solved? (eg in an interaction framework)

What philosophical stances are there towards engaging with or understanding this reconciliation?

Comment: Please define these three concepts of time and state the problem, which has to be solved.

Comment: @JoWehler they come from personal, work and spirituality like faith , study and practice

Comment: Regarding the edit of the question, I don't "see" how "actual" time in the original question was formed as "theoretical physics" time; is it implied that physics has the unique privilege of explaining reality?

Comment: Psychological subjective time is thinking 'this is a slow day'. On the other hand, phenomenological subjective time is practically unnoticed because one's self actualises temporally; it changes—time is part of its constitution, so time in this sense is unconscious and not strictly linear (e.g. can be immune to entropy).  The connection to thermodynamic time, as it relates to the caesuim standard, is that human selves measured it that way.  Maybe there is a further cosmic standard that could measure time in the plasma of the Big Bang. In string theory, F-theory apparently has 2 time dimensions.

Comment: To clarify, let's not assume phenomenological subjective time is congruent with thermodynamic time, or string theory time. It is mysterious, poorly understood, but simply just not necessarily the same as thermodynamic time, so it can stand in its own category at the very least. It is probably impossible to say anything about phenomenological subjective time (if it cannot be perceived) except that being is temporal, whereas things can be said about the caesium standard (thermodynamic time), especially its definition.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen: 'The circadian coordination of cell biology' https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5057284 Our foundational sense of time passing is celular, & emergent. We know total anaesthesia & other brain conditions can eliminate our subjective sense of time passed eg while asleep. Shannon Channels shows that thermodynamic time applies to the decay of signals, ie flow of information. We need to understand how our intuitions about time arise, exactly so we can question them in relation to cases we can't directly experience, like small scales, high velocities & in strong gravity wells

Comment: At what cost? (We have normal moral concerns as well)

Comment: The quote appears to be mostly unrelated to the question. Is this a question about perceptions of time and thermodynamics, or is it a question about axioms in quantum mechanics and general relativity?

Comment: This questions been edited to the point at which the current version is quite unlike the original

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is this: psychological time means that time must exists since I have a perception of it. Then, thermodynamic time means that the perception of time I have, is not illusory, since time has non-reversible effects in physical reality. So, I conclude that actual time indeed exists and goes forward. From this, I hope that this "going forward" of time, may give meaning to things, and subsequently to my life.

---

After the edit of the question - since my answer now seems a little bit poetic - I would like to add a comment.

As far as the "problem of time" (in the context of theoretical physics) although I am not an expert, I "see" Marco Ocram 's answer as sufficient.

By regarding the "psychological experience of time" since it is tightly linked to consciousness, the reconciliation you suggest perhaps has to be investigated in the "quantum physics and consciousness" perpective. Maybe an expert in this field could elaborate on this, although I find it hard.

> “...This is quite a mystery since it seems that our conscious
> experience cannot arise from the brain, and in fact, cannot arise from
> any physical process.”

*Dr. Nir Lahav*

Comment: Hardly an answer, though.

Comment: At least I made a try in the context of the question; you edited the question! and formed it according to your beliefs.

Comment: This is a Q & **A** site. See site guidance: 'How do I write a good answer?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer & have a look at other answers for the kind of standard expected. This is not Reddit. Try to source references and cite texts, & relate your answers to well-regarded philosophical work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by the 'problem'. The psychological perception of time is still the subject of investigation, with several factors appearing to contribute to it. You can find a round-up here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4830363/

I assume that by 'thermodynamic' time you mean the so-called 'arrow of time' that is often written about in relation to entropy. This is well understood and a matter of probabilities. Many processes are commonplace in one direction but vanishingly unlikely in another.

'Real' time for practical purposes is well explained by general and special relativity, although some research in physics suggests that time might ultimately be granular, whereas relativity considers it to be smooth, which is an approximation that works well for must current purposes.

There continues to be a range of conflicting philosophical ideas about time, but whether you consider that to be 'a problem' is a matter of personal outlook.

Addendum

Since you have edited your question substantially, allow me to edit my answer.

The quote you have cited suggests that quantum theorists and the proponents of relativity are at loggerheads over the nature of time. That is simply untrue. Quantum theory is a particular model of reality, as are Newtonian mechanics and special relativity. Each of them has a domain of applicability in which they very accurately agree with reality. We have yet to come up with a 'theory of everything' which makes accurate predictions over all domains, but that does not invalidate the relevance of the existing theories to their applicable domains.

Comment: No, it's a well established & clearly defined problem in physics relating to reconciling Relativity & QFT.

Comment: @CriglCragl sure- both are approximate models with different domains of applicability. The technical complexities of finding a model that encompasses both are enormous. I'm not convinced that the nature of time, per se, is top of the list of difficulties.

Comment: @CriglCragl besides, what ever model we arrive at that spans both domains, it must approximate relativity very precisely, since we know that GR and SR are accurate models of reality in the macroscopic domain over timescales that are appreciable by the human mind.